# Determine if you own app is currently installed or not programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I am creating a new feature in one of my apps to show a "What's New" page. I have this all working as expected and it compares the last version (stored) to the current version, then updates the current version once the feature list is shown.

This all works great and as expected. The issue I have now is determining if a user already has the app installed.

Case 1) If the user is a completely new user and it is the first time they have downloaded the app, then the new feature list should not be shown.

Case 2) If they already had the app installed and are updating their app to a new version, then we need to show the new feature list.

The part I need help with is Case 2. How can you determine if the app is already installed by the user, without having to release a minor update just to set a `currentInstalledVersion` variable beforehand?

Comment: If your app has  registered URL scheme you can check to see if the URL scheme can be opened using canOpenURL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you are asking for. Are you asking if its possible to check if the previous version of the current app was installed as new or as an update?

Comment: I am trying to find the users which update the app, not new installs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(currentInstalledVersion)
{
   if(currentInstalledVersion < actualCurrentVersion)
   {
      // user upgraded
   }
}
else
{
   if(someOtherDataSavedOnDiskExists)
   {
      // user had the app with a version before you implemented currentInstalledVersion and is updating
   }
   else
   {
     // fresh install
   }
}
```

**Update based on below comment**

Okay in that case, there is no built-in mechanism to help you with this. Until you implement a way yourself (with this flag), you can't check. However, if you have any kind of other flags or data you've written to `NSUserDefaults` for instance, you can check that immediately on startup to see if those values are set which would tell you it is an existing user that just installed the app (only check the other flags if `currentInstalledVersion` is not set). If you have not written any data to disk or to `NSUserDefaults` then you are out of luck for your initial release of this feature.

I updated the code above to reflect this.

Comment: Not quite. The currently installed versions of the app out there at the moment would not have the currentInstalledVersion flag set or exist for that matter... I am trying to find the users that have the app installed and then upgrade to this new version. As opposed to the completely new installed users

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought. In fact I tried to check the NSUserDefaults but the valueForKey is always returning empty in the `+(void)initialize` function

Comment: What are you checking or, do you have another field you've saved in previous releases? The best place to do this stuff is probably in your `AppDelegate` right at the beginning of `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Because we only registerDefaults for the NSUserDefaults it looks like they are only kept the lifetime of the app open and not stored completely. So it doesn't look like I can check those unless they are set.

Comment: in the initalize we set a lot of NSUserDefaults registerDefaults. So by the time `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called they are already set for new/existing users

Comment: Yeah, you can't use that method if you want things to persist in between app launches. If that's what you've been doing you are out of luck, and make sure you don't do it moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSUserDefault and set a bool to check if it's a new user.
ex:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"user"]){
  // it's a new user
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES ForKey:@"user"];
}
```

The `boolForKey:` method would return `NO` if the default was not set.

Comment: Except we are looking for the users that have the current build installed. Therefore this would not exist. It would work going forward, but we already have something in place for that... It was more about the current situation/build out there now